# Riley is leaving

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My suffix is growing.
> My infix is packing.
> My prefix is moving.
> My whole is earning.

*Hint upon request:*

> A good Riley riddle has layers, and so I have layers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are a:

> **CABBAGE**!

*My suffix is growing.*

> One's **AGE** is always *growing*, increasing by the second...

*My infix is packing.*

> A **BAG** can be used for *packing* (e.g. at the supermarket, or when going away on holiday).

*My prefix is moving.*

> A (taxi-)**CAB** can often be seen *moving* around large cities.

*My whole is earning.*

> **CABBAGE** is also a slang term for [money](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cabbage), which you can *earn*.

As for the title:

> Cabbages have **leaves**! (And as for the hint: These leaves are *layered*!)

Answer (score 1):

Could be

> wages

My suffix is growing:

> ages

My infix is packing:

> AGE Industries

My prefix is moving:

> wag

My whole is earning:

> wages

Answer (score 0):

Is it maybe

> Proceeds?

*My suffix is growing*

> "ceeds". A wordplay on seeds.

*My infix is packing*

> CE. Is this referring to [CE](https://www.google.com/search?q=ce%20packaging&ei=HhKBYfabEYSwrgS5qKaAAg&oq=ce%20packaging&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIFCAAQgAQyCAgAEAcQBRAeMgYIABAFEB46BwgAEEcQsAM6CAgAEAgQBxAeOggIABANEAUQHjoICAAQCBANEB5KBAhBGABQ7CZYhS9glzJoAXACeAGAAXCIAYwFkgEDNi4ymAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj2otq1u_nzAhUEmIsKHTmUCSAQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)?

*My prefix is moving*

> proceed. Synonym for *move* forward

*My whole is earning*

> [proceeds](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proceeds)

The title:

> Goodbye. A wordplay on *good buy*