# What job is found in this riddle?

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

My prefix is asleep.
My infix is what my whole is doing.
My suffix is bowling.
My whole is packing.

What am I?

Hint:

> as the title suggests, my whole is the name of a type of job.

Comment: Inspired by trying (and failing) to solve [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/112425/5373).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> **REMOVER**

*My prefix is asleep.*

> Somebody experiencing [**REM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_eye_movement_sleep) *is asleep*.

*My infix is what my whole is doing.*

> A remover's role is to **MOVE** something from one place to another.

*My suffix is bowling.*

> An **OVER** is a cricket term for a set of six balls *bowled* by the bowler.

*My whole is packing.*

> You will very likely find a **REMOVER** *packing* items from your home in order to take them to your new place!

Comment: Yep, you got it!

Answer (score 2):

As replied by pos(t)er, it isn’t . . .

> . . . “(k)napsacking.”

Thought it was because . . .

> . . . “nap” is a short sleep
>  while “sack” is a colloquialism
>  for storing one’s belonings.

And, well, . . .

> . . . kingpin is vital to bowl down.

Always worth a try.

Comment: No, but I'm interested to see your explanation for the four parts anyway.

Comment: I tried, @Rand al'Thor.  You riddle me.

Comment: Thank you for the ^vote.  Think i spelled "knap" without the "k."  Correct me if i'm khumn.